# Recurring/repeated tasks in GNOME Evolution

Tags: gnome, 18.04, evolution

Is it possible to set up recurring tasks (say weekly or monthly) in Gnome's Evolution mail client? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recurring Tasks has been a long requested feature it seems, but haven't been supported  see [here](http://gnome-evolution-general.1774414.n4.nabble.com/workaround-for-recurring-tasks-tp4662366p4662372.html). A simple (and perhaps standard) work around is to schedule a recurring appointment or meeting.

There **is** a patch to add this functionality see [this](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/evolution/commit/8197757ed) commit. The patch was committed to the master Evolution branch about 5 months ago and is available upstream (3.29.1+) but it hasn't made it into the Bionic universe repositories yet. You can download the source and build it yourself, or wait till it makes it into a Bionic package.